# English equivalent to the Portuguese expression “entendedores entenderão”, “those who understand understand”?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

In Portuguese, “entendedores entenderão”, which literally can be translated to “those who understand understand”, is often used on the internet.

Someone might write this when (s)he posts something that only people with knowledge on the subject would be able to comprehend. For example, when posting a joke about mathematics.

Is there an idiomatic expression that means the same thing in English? I tried googling the phrase “whoever gets it”, hoping it would lead to some expression, but I did not find anything.

Comment: An "inside joke" or an "in-joke".

Comment: Reminds me of a rather clever advertising slogan that the Washington Post used to use: "If you don't get it, you don't get it."

Comment: He that has ears to hear, let him hear.

Comment: Nudge nudge. Wink wink. Say no more.

Comment: I would tell you a UDP joke, but you might not get it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The common expression in English is **"If you know, you know."**

*[Urbandictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=If%20You%20Know%2C%20You%20Know)* has a good definition:

> The defining phrase of an inside joke/access to information only a select few know about

Answer (score 6):

Since those who understand will understand without much explanation ...

[**A word to the wise is sufficient.**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20word%20to%20the%20wise)

The saying introduces a statement as advice:
*A word to the wise*—never sign a contract without reading it first.

Comment: Or if you're really fancy, *[verb sap](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/verb-sap)* which is an abbreviation of the Latin.

Answer (score 2):

I have heard:

> ***(Only) Those in the know will understand.***

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-the-know) explains that

> If you are ***in the know*** about something, especially something that is not known about or understood by many people, you have information about it.

Answer (score 1):

*Inside joke* is quite common:

> **inside joke**
>
> : a joke that is understood only by people with special knowledge
> about something
>
> ([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inside%20joke))

A more general term is "*esoteric*":

> **esoteric**
>
> intended for or likely to be understood by only a small number of people with a specialized knowledge or interest.
>
> (Oxford)
>
> *Esoteric joke/pun/statement/concept*

Answer (score 0):

For the usage given in the question:

> For example, when posting a joke about mathematics

I suggest

> **in-joke**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> A joke that is understood or appreciated by only a small group of people.

Also **inside joke**.

From Lexico [here](https://www.lexico.com/definition/in-joke) and [here](https://www.lexico.com/definition/inside_joke).